# Why LRESULT CALLBACK is used in this function?

Tags: c++, c

Recently, I've started to learn DX11 and I was trying to create message loops in WinAPI. I saw a LRESULT CALLBACK function from the tutorial that I haven't seen before. It is called in Window Procedure function. Here is the WndProc function and the MessageHandler function(the function that I'm talking about).

WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT umessage, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
switch(umessage)
{
    // Check if the window is being destroyed.
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    // Check if the window is being closed.
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);     
        return 0;
    }

    // All other messages pass to the message handler in the system class.
    default:
    {
        return ApplicationHandle->MessageHandler(hwnd, umessage, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
}
```

MessageHandler:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT umsg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
switch(umsg)
{
    // Check if a key has been pressed on the keyboard.
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        // If a key is pressed send it to the input object so it can record that state.
        m_Input->KeyDown((unsigned int)wparam);
        return 0;
    }

    // Check if a key has been released on the keyboard.
    case WM_KEYUP:
    {
        // If a key is released then send it to the input object so it can unset the state for that key.
        m_Input->KeyUp((unsigned int)wparam);
        return 0;
    }

    // Any other messages send to the default message handler as our application won't make use of them.
    default:
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, umsg, wparam, lparam);
    }
}
}
```

What I don't understand is, why we added the "LRESULT CALLBACK" part to the MessageHandler function? I know, we must add it to WndProc function, but I don't get the point of creating a new function and adding it a calling convention. What if we don't add any calling convention to the MessageHandler function? What if we didn't create the MessageHandler funciton and write the KEY_DOWN listeners to WndProc's switch-case statement?

These codes are in one class and ApplicationHandler pointer points to "this".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no obvious reason for `SystemClass::MessageHandler` to be declared as `CALLBACK` because it cannot be used as a message handler for Windows since it is not `static`. There is no reason for `SystemClass::MessageHandler` to be declared as `CALLBACK` in the code you showed.

Answer (score 3):

About the `CALLBACK` (`__stdcall`):
Functions called from "within Windows" just have to be `stdcall` because Windows developers decided to write/compile Windows that it calls stdcall functions. In theory, any CC could be used, but Windows and your code must have the same.
Your own function won´t need it if you´re using it only in your own code in your program.

`LRESULT` (some int/pointer-like thing) is just the return type.
The reason for not just writing int (or something like that) is that `LRESULT` is a int with a certain length etc., and if MS decides to change it for some reason, they only need to change the definition of `LRESULT`, but not every function which has a `LRESULT` return type.

Comment: Do I need it in MessageHandler function now? And why I should need it to call MessageHandler function from outside of the code?

Comment: (If you need an more detailed explanation on something in my text, please say what is unclear and why.)

Comment: I didn't want to ask too much questions, because I think, calling conventions is about low-leveled computer language, and I don't have any experience with it. Actually, I understand the general using of LRESULT and __stdcall, and I understand that I don't need to add LRESULT CALLBACK to MessageHandler at this code too. I'm confused of why tutorial used a calling convention if it didn't have to use. I mean, MessageHandler is called in WndProc function, not by Windows, why did it used LRESULT CALLBACK for it? I think, this is a nonsense question, because you didn't see the source code.

Comment: Don´t know what tutorial you´re reading, but maybe the author didn´t know it too (that it isn´t needed here).

Comment: Probably it is. My problem about this usage of __stdcall is solved though.